# Google App Engine The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been handle a wierd issue.

I have a service - (serviceA)
https://l2-main-dot-winky-products.uc.r.appspot.com/

and I connect it in the dispach.yaml file into the subdomain - l2.web3m.io

`- url: "l2.web3m.io/*" service: l2-main`

The serviceA works fine with GAE default domain, but when try to reach this service through the subdomain i gets:

`404. That’s an error.

The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.`

On cloud platform its seems that the connection is working:

[image]

yaml file:

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs16
service: l2-main
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static
  - url: /beta
    static_files: build/beta/index.html
    upload: build/beta/index.html
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$
  - url: .*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: build/favicon.ico
    upload: build/favicon.ico
env_variables:
  APP_ENV: "production"
  NODE_ENV: "production"
```

What do I do wrong ?

I've tried to reach the subdomain l2.web3m.io and got 404 error

---

SOLVED:

The problem was with the yaml file,

There we have /beta with the statis files in - build/beta/index.html  which was a wrong path :\

After fixing the path it works fine.

Comment: Was it working previously? Have you followed this instructions on [mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/mapping-custom-domains)?

Comment: Thank you Robert, This is a new subdomain. But we found the problem in the yaml file. I updated the question.

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer so that it would be helpful to other community members with similar concerns.

Comment: The problem was with the yaml file,

There we have /beta with the statis files in - build/beta/index.html which was a wrong path :\

After fixing the path it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Shani, they resolved it by fixing the path.

> The problem was with the yaml file,
>
> There we have /beta with the statis files in - build/beta/index.html
> which was a wrong path :\
>
> After fixing the path it works fine.

Always make sure that the path is correct to prevent `404` error.